# Is possible to add annotation @ManagedBean in XPages?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

I try to add annotations in a Java class to take the bean in XPages.
But when I try this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="photoBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PhotoBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6839844250507324282L;

    private String idPhoto;
    private String nomPhoto;

    public String getIdPhoto() {
        return idPhoto;
    }

    public void setIdPhoto(String idPhoto) {
        this.idPhoto = idPhoto;
    }


}
```

it doesn't compile:

```
@ManagedBean(name="photoBean")
@SessionScoped
```

Is there special code to do that? Or is it only for Java EE and not for Lotus?
Notes says to create the annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they said, no, it is not possible to use the annotations in Xpages.  DARN!  Yeah, i want them too.  Anyway the way to go about registering your Beans is through the faces-config.xml file.  (package explorer view, application/WebContent/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml) The XML would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>ErrWriter</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>de.hol.utils.errorHandling.ErrorWriter</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
  <!--AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER: Automatically generated by IBM Domino Designer. Do not modify.-->
  <!--AUTOGEN-END-BUILDER: End of automatically generated section-->
</faces-config>
```

Happy Programming!

Comment: thanks, but i have two models .ntf which inherited (A-->B) and a base C.nsf of B. B has managed-beans specific and it has been removed when i update design A to B. This is because i want to use annotations... There is another solution ?

Comment: Excellent question. I wish I knew a quick and easy answer, but I don't. If I were going to employ such a pattern that DB-A defines some beans, DB-B defines/(Expands the first into) more Beans, then DB-C uses some of both, I probably would want to get into OSGI and define my own plug-ins.  That allows DB-C to use 'Beans' from 'DB-A' and 'DB-B', while allowing DB-D to only use the ones defined in 'DB-B'.  Although such a jump is not made overnight.  I've been struggling for a while with it.  Keep in mind that dbs marked with '' are libraries then and not templates.

Answer (score 3):

Annotations for managed beans have been introduced after JSF 2.0. But XPages is based on JSF 1.1.

So you cannot use such annotations in XPages.

Update:

Make sure you have checked Jesse's blog entry:

https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/a-quick--dirty--and-inefficient-%40managedbean-implementation-in-xpages

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Long answer: the JSF implementation in XPages doesn't implement Java EE 6.0 and JSF 2.0 where annotations are defined. You need to edit your faces-config.xml to include a managed bean