# Spring Annotations in XPages Java classes

Tags: java, spring, xpages, lotus-domino

I'm trying to use Spring annotations in Domino XPages Java classes. Spring works when I'm defining beans in the configuration file. However I fail to use the annotations.

To illustrate the problem, I have created two simple empty classes annotated with `@Component` annotation - `com.geo168.a.B` (`@Component public class B {}`) and `com.geo168.a.C` (`@Component public class C {}`)

The first one I have created in Eclipse, packed and added to the application in a jar. The second one I add directly in Code/Java section.

I add a component-scan tag in the configuration file: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.geo168.a"/>` and try to instantiate the classes:

```
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(SPRING_CONFIG); 
        // class defined in the jar, works ok
        com.geo168.a.B b = ctx.getBean(com.geo168.a.B.class);
        // class defined in Code/Java, throws exception
        com.geo168.a.C c = ctx.getBean(com.geo168.a.C.class);
```

I get an error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.geo168.a.C] is defined`

Spring has found the annotated class only in the JAR file. It works if I add the bean explicitly to the configuration file:

```
<bean class="com.geo168.a.C"/>
```

A similar post: [Is possible to add annotation @ManagedBean in XPages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800360/is-possible-to-add-annotation-managedbean-in-xpages) seems to address only the particular JSF annotations (that do not work, because they are not implemented).

In the Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection I find a note: `The scanning of classpath packages requires the presence of corresponding directory entries in the classpath. When you build JARs with Ant, make sure that you do not activate the files-only switch of the JAR task.`

Could this be somehow related? I do not know in what form Domino deploys the classes internally.